# What's causing bloat on opensuse Docker?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

So I pulled down the opensuse Docker--only 94M, nice!

I created a Docker file like this:

```
FROM opensuse

RUN zypper --non-interactive install tar
RUN zypper --non-interactive clean -a
RUN rm -rf /var/log/zypp /var/log/zypper.log
```

The 'tar' command and its dependencies require ~3M, but the resulting image is 140M!  I've cleaned the cache and killed the logs, so what else is causing the roughly 40M bloat here?

Comment: you can take a look what remains in /var/cache/zypp directory

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the whole operation in one `RUN` command

```
RUN zypper --non-interactive install tar \
  && zypper --non-interactive clean -a \
  && rm -rf /var/log/zypp /var/log/zypper.log
```

As docker does a commit after each line

redacted history

```
$ docker history  test
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f0c1173538b0        2 minutes ago        /bin/sh -c zypper --non-interactive install t   7.429 MB
80bd0f661aef        3 weeks ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:4c338e205c079dbf5d   97.78 MB
da0e7dee81d7        8 weeks ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER Flavio Castelli    0 B
```